# Speed up SELECT query on large table

Tags: mysql, sql

How I can improve my query time? I have a table for saving money transactions with these fields:

```
id, customersId, paymentId, amount, cash, createDate
```

My query gets a customers transactions:

```
SELECT id,amount,cash,createDate
FROM customers_transactions
WHERE customersId = 2784
```

This table has 10 million record or more. The query takes about 13 seconds to execute.

The table has these indexes:

```
id, customersId (unique)
customersId, createDate (unique)
```

And these partitions:

```
10 partiotions By RANGE on customersId
LESS THAN 1000
LESS THAN 2000
LESS THAN 3000
LESS THAN 4000
LESS THAN 5000
LESS THAN 6000
LESS THAN 7000
LESS THAN 8000
LESS THAN 9000
LESS THAN 10000
```

The server has 8 GB of RAM, with CORE i5 3.2GHz

I want run this query less than 0.5 sec

Comment: Have you done an EXPLAIN of the query? Have you used OPTIMIZE on the table? The query is quite simple so I would have expected it to pick up the relevant index quite easily and use that.

Comment: try an index on `customersId` only. Or reverse the column order in the `id, customersId` index. In a SQL implementation I'm familiar with the "sub index" in a compound index - that is `customersId` in this case - would not be utilized by itself; as in `where customersId = 2784`. If referencing the 1st column of that index then the index clearly was utilized.

Comment: In MySQL it should use the first part of the index in this case. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/multiple-column-indexes.html

Comment: Something doesn't adds up here. Can you please check the execution plan ans share it? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Get rid from the partitions, unless you need them for something else.

We can create covering index (index contains all needed columns), but It is an overkill.

Also -
Make Id a primary key and throw `id, customersId (unique)`

P.s.
Why did you had `createDate` to `customersId, createDate (unique)`?

Comment: if a table have a primary key then partiotions key must on primary key. if i make id primary then i cant partiotioning my table by customersId. createDate index make result range in smaller range.by this index my query is 3 sec,without this is 13 sec

Comment: Therefore - `Get rid from the partitions, unless you need them for something else.`